# Returning valid JSON from JSON Formatter on HTTP OK for WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I use WebAPI for various REST calls, and have always on success (when I don't need data) just used

`return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);`

However with [jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-ajax-returning-a-json-result-of-an-empty-string) having a breaking change in it that requires JSON to always be sent I need to some how update so that instead of `NULL` I send `{}`.

Is there a better way to return a OK message with Valid JSON, currently it just returns an empty string (`NULL`)?

NOTE: I still want to retain the possibility of returning XML if the users Accept type requests it so I believe I need to either do something with the formatter or use something that’s not a `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: what does your jQuery call look like - maybe that's a better place to change things rather than modifying the response in an ugly way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);  // 204 Status Code
```

This is how you are supposed to indicate that there will be body content.  jQuery should respect this.

I did some hunting and in fact, this was done 5 months ago in jQuery in [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/eb47553eeac58861bcefac063c0e03e161b4d52c) commit.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is the best practice here and may be someone from ASP.NET Web API team can answer but this works.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse<object>(HttpStatusCode.OK, new object());
}
```

Comment: Actually you only need: return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new object());